# Need help on how to search through multiple text files for a string

Tags: php

Right now it's only searching through one text file but I want it to search through a whole directory but I don't know how to go about that :/

```
<?php
$searchfor = "example";
$file = 'file.txt';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern  = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern  = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
echo "<pre>Matches were found for $searchfor:\n";
echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
?>
```

Instead of just searching through the one file "file.txt", I want it to search through a whole directory of files to find the string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$searchfor = "example";
$dir = ".";
$pattern  = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern  = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
        echo "<pre>Matches were found for $searchfor:\n";
        echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When I ran that, I got a bunch of these things... http://prntscr.com/d9gv3p

Comment: You need to specify a directory path in `$dir`. The way I wrote the code it runs in the current directory of the script so it is only finding the matches that are in the script.